# Recording both logs and unexpected errors in a Log file in Python

Tags: python, logging, tkinter, stderr, error-logging

What is the best way to record logs as well as unexpected errors in to an output file in python 2.7? Currently I use *logging* module and *sys.stderr* together to create a log file in this manner (logs from logging module are directed into stderr so as to record both programmed logs and unexpected errors in output file).

But the problem here is, if the application throws an unexpected error, the only way to see those unexpected errors is - to close the opened GUI window and then and then only, those unexpected errors are recorded into log file. Is there a way to get this done without exiting the application?

The script below demonstrates this problem:

```
import sys, logging
from Tkinter import *

sys.stderr = open('log.txt', 'w')       # directs logs and errors from terminal into log.txt 
logging.basicConfig( level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(name)-14s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
gui_log = logging.getLogger('gui')
gui_log.info('This will go into log.txt')    # log will be directed to stdout

def browse(b):              # this function will throw an (unexpected!) error  
    a = b + 1

# gui window that will throw an unexpected error when button is clicked
app = Tk()
app.title("DemoLimo")
app.geometry("")

button_seq = Button(app, text = 'Select file', bg = 'red', command = browse)
button_seq.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Note: **Ideally, I would like to record both programmed logs and unexpected errors into an output file**. If you have a better handling for this situation, I welcome your thoughts!

Comment: use try-catch block, for try it will be log and in catch it will be ur error log

Comment: I do use try blocks. But depending on users and situations, I get new and unexpected errors at times and that's what has led me here!

Comment: You probably ought to use those "unexpected errors" as input to your code improvement process - every time you get one, fix the code so that that condition will in the future be handled in a reasonable manner. Continue until you never get another "unexpected error". That's part of the software evolution cycle...

Comment: Though I agree, this is one of those applications for which logging the errors is more beneficial as the time being spent on fine-tuning this application may not be worth the effort (at least for now). Hoped someone had figured this trick on logging!